# Get total price after ajax update in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to take the price in the filter `woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments`, but failing to understand where it resides

```
add_filter('woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'price_bottom_checkout');
function price_bottom_checkout($arr) {
    $price = ? // how to get it over here?      
    $price_txt = '<span class="total-pay">'.$price.'</span>';
    $arr['.total-pay'] = $price;
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find out how. Needed to see the session cart which is updated on every cart refresh via ajax.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'price_bottom_checkout');
function price_bottom_checkout($arr) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $the_total = '';
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item) {
        $the_total = $cart_item['line_total'];
        break;
    }
    $price_txt = '<span class="total-pay">'.wc_price($the_total).'</span>';
    $arr['.total-pay'] = $price_txt;
    return $arr;
}
```